# Variance and conditional independence

Tags: probability, statistics

Random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ are conditionaly independent, given a random variable $\Theta$ and their conditional distibutions satisfy $E(X_i|\Theta)=10\Theta$ and $Var(X_i|\Theta)=100\Theta^2$.
$N$ is a random variable conditionally independet of $X_1,X_2,...$, given $\Theta$ with a conditional distibution $P(N=n|\Theta=\theta)=n(1-\theta)^{n-1}\theta^2$. $\Theta$ has a density: $$p(\theta)=\begin{cases} 6\theta(1-\theta) & \mbox{ for } \theta \in (0,1) \\ 0 & \mbox{ otherwise } \end{cases}.$$ Let's define $$S_N= \begin{cases}\sum_{k=1}^NX_k & \mbox{ for } N>0 \\ 0 & \mbox{ for } N=0 \end{cases}.$$ $Var(\frac{S_N}{N})=?$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using the formula $Var(\frac{S_N}{N})=E Var(\frac{S_N}{N}|\Theta)+Var E (\frac{S_N}{N}|\Theta)$ , but I didn't get anywhere

Comment: and the problem is that want to have $N$ in condition and I don't know to get the second condition

Comment: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. Moreover, we know that $E(X) = E(E(X|Y))$. Now, you just need to write things...

Comment: Finally, you can write that $E(E(X|Y|Z)) := E(E(E(X|Y)|Z)) = E(E(E(X|Z)|Y))$

Comment: Thanks. I got the correct answer by using $(N,\Theta)$ as a condition in the first place, i.e. $Var(\frac{S_N}{N})=E Var(\frac{S_N}{N}|(\Theta,N))+Var E (\frac{S_N}{N}|(\Theta,N))$ and the fact, that $E(\frac{S_N}{N}|(\Theta,N))=10\Theta$ and $Var(\frac{S_N}{N}|(\Theta,N))=\frac{100 \Theta^2}{N}$. Is this method also correct?

Comment: I didn't do the computations, but if you write things correctly indicating the values taken by $N$ and $\Theta$, you should get the correct answer.